# Server terminated early with status 2 error while running e2e tests on windows

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, npm, protractor

I'm working on an angular 2 app and for that I've configured protractor for end-2-end testing. but when I try to run the test cases, I get the following error

```
[11:53:45] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[11:53:45] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[11:53:45] E/launcher - Server terminated early with status 2
[11:53:45] E/launcher - Error: Server terminated early with status 2
at Error (native)
at C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\remote\index.js:242:20
at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1379:14)
at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
at asyncRun (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2775:27)
at C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
[11:53:45] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

webdriver-manager version: **10.3.0**

node version: **6.11.0**

npm version: **3.8.6**

protractor version: **4.0.9**

Environment: **Windows**

I've searched the web but unable to find solution for the issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Check if something is already running on port `4444` and also run `webdriver-manager update` and `webdriver-manager start` to check if selenium server works find on your machine

Comment: While you are at it, you might want to upgrade your protractor too. It's currently on 5.1.2